# Output multiple files using Rollup

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, rollup

I am using Rollup to bundle my code for production.
I have multiple js files, so I am using the Rollup `plugin-multi-entry` plugin to use a glob pattern to target all of my js files.
I am outputting the files in `umd` format.

Currently they are being output as one js file, bundled all together, this is the expected behavior, but I would like to out put them all individually as well, transpiled to es5 and in umd format but not concatonated into one js bundle file, how can I do this?

Current setup:

```
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import multi from "@rollup/plugin-multi-entry";
import gzipPlugin from "rollup-plugin-gzip";

export default [{
    input: "src/**/*.logic.js",
    output: {
        dir: "build/assets/js",
        format: "umd",
        name: "Logic"
    },
    plugins: [
        gzipPlugin(),
        multi({
            exports: true
        }),
        babel({
            exclude: "node_modules/**"
        })
    ]
}]
```

Comment: It looks like this plugin can come to help https://github.com/alfredosalzillo/rollup-plugin-multi-input

Answer (score 7):

https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#configuration-files

Here's an example:

```
export default [
  {
    input: 'main-a.js',
    output: {
      file: 'dist/bundle-a.js',
      format: 'cjs'
    }
  },
  {
    input: 'main-b.js',
    output: [
      {
        file: 'dist/bundle-b1.js',
        format: 'cjs'
      },
      {
        file: 'dist/bundle-b2.js',
        format: 'es'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should able to do that with [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org) without any plugins.

Take a look at the [code splitting section](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#code-splitting) from their documentation.